# Tuple of shared_ptr from variadic template?

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, shared-ptr

Take the following snippet as a base:

```
template<typename Type1, typename Type2>
auto Foo() {
    std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Type1>, std::shared_ptr<Type2>> example;
}
```

How should I go about creating my tuple of shared pointers when using a variadic template?

```
template<typename... Types>
auto Foo() {
    // How to create the tuple?
}
```

There are tons of tuple and variadic template related questions here. Some seem to address this ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305395/how-to-create-a-tuple-of-vectors-of-type-deduced-from-a-variadic-template-in-c), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922095/creating-tuple-of-types-derived-from-variadic-template-pack)), but still feel too convoluted (honestly, the answers went over my head, but may well be the simplest way).

My attempt used recursive templates and `std::tuple_cat`, but this creates many "sub-tuples" along the way, which is far from ideal.

**In short**: is there a "simpler" or "more direct" approach to this problem? Something that doesn't require multiple functions, recursive calls and whatnot, kinda like `std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Types...>>`?

Comment: How about std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Types>...>?

Comment: Time to learn about [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) introduced alongside variadic templates in C++11. It removes a lot of the need for the old recursive style.

Comment: @Useless I thought I knew about it, but that's obviously not the case :/

Comment: Always more to learn!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expand the pack:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Types>
auto Foo() {
   using tup = std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Types>...>;
   return tup{};
}

int main() {
  auto f = Foo<int,double>();
  static_assert( std::is_same_v< std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<int>,std::shared_ptr<double>>,decltype(f)>);
}
```

For convenience you can use an alias:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...Types>
using SharedTuple = std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Types>...>;

int main() {
  static_assert( std::is_same_v< std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<int>,std::shared_ptr<double>>,SharedTuple<int,double>>);
}
```

Comment: So you're saying I almost got it right with my example? I had no idea this was a thing, please imagine a thunderclap as I facepalm hard.